# Изображение на фоне

Tags: html, css, изображения, background

У меня есть блок, к примеру, с ID "topic". Хочу поставить на фон изображение так, чтобы оно, независимо от ширины блока, всегда адаптировалось под ширину.
К примеру, у меня фон шириной 1920px, а блок - 100px. Как сделать, чтобы фон принимал размер 100px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.topic{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
Position, top, left - я добавил исключительно что бы отступы поставить;

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topic"></div>
```

Comment: Вместо значения "cover" свойства "background-size" использовал "contain". Так всё работает :)